# Singular vs. plural in "interest rates and investment"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I found this sentence in a dictionary:

> The tenuous link between interest rates and investment.

Why is *interest rates* plural here but *investment* not? I know investment is a countable noun, so shouldn't it be *investments* (or both just use singular nouns with no article, like *interest rate* and *investment*) in order to match before and after *and*?

Comment: BTW this isn't a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> The tenuous link between **interest rates** and **investment**

This is correct because *interest rates* are values that change over time. Also there are various rates for different products.

In this interpretation, *investment* would be an activity (like *running*), not a thing, so you don't make it plural.

You could say:

> The tenuous link between interest rates and **investments**

But in this case, *investments* refers to those specific investment products (like a savings account and some stocks) where there can be more than one.

More context is needed to know which option is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different

> **interest rates**

and these rates are usually shown shown on a graph over different durations to create a **yield curve**

Without seeing more of your excerpt, my interpretation is it is either referring how interest rates effect investing in interest rates and therefore the singular, or how it effects the act of investing money: investment

> investment**s**

usually refers to the different types of things or assets to invest in